# Flexible image sizing inside flexbox container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout with an image and a caption (stacked). I'd like the image to take up all the available screen space, minus whatever space the caption needs below. Each image + caption combo should never exceed 100% of the viewport height.

The problem: I'm struggling finding a way to make the image not exceed the height of the available space. (In other words, the image will be larger than the available area, and it needs to scale down to respect the `100vh` height set on `<section>` in my code example below.

[Example of desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmZnt.png)

Image space outlined in **red**, caption space outlined in **blue**

[Demo of problem](https://codepen.io/watilo/pen/vqqrzz)

I added a `max-height` to the `<img>` so you can see the desired effect. (Remove `max-height` on the `<img>` to see the problem.)

Ultimately I need it to work like this without setting a literal `max-height`. Effectively it should be `max-height: calc(100vh - (height of caption))`, but I'm trying to do this without javascript.

Comment: You need to imbricate your flex boxes and use overflow : hidden so a max-height:100% can be calculated within the boundarie of your parent, else it overflows and height:XX% is calculated as usual only from the parent if it has an height set : example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZddMbq

Answer (score 0):

*From earlier comment*

to keep `flex` children inside boundaries  and use a max-size in %, you need to use `overflow:hidden`;, so the browser can calculate those size, else content boxes can overflow.

example:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1vmax;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* the browser will calculate size */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

figure {
  padding: 1vmin;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* the browser will calculate size */
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <nav>
    Link Link Link
  </nav>
</header>

<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/1200/1200" />
  </figure>

  <aside>
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum #1</strong>
    <p>Vivamus a neque dui. Nunc tortor risus, mattis quis vulputate at, lacinia vel enim. Nam aliquet ipsum a mi malesuada, nec accumsan felis accumsan.</p>
  </aside>
</section>
```